# 1st activity get response from 5th activity

Tags: android

Here is a thing, i'm new in android. I'm making wizard sign up form like facebook and i have 5 activity.

1st activity - input email, 
2nd activity - input name, 
3rd activity - input phone number,
4th activity - input password, 
5th activity - show progress while connect with web service to store user on the server side.

So far so good.

But I want when the server return "user with this email exist", go back to the 1st activity and prompt user to enter other email and when user click submit, instead of go to 2nd activity, resend to server side.

Here is my code:

**1st Activity**

```
    public class SignUp2stp extends Activity{
    private  Button button;
    private  EditText email;
    private static final String EMAIL_PATTERN = "^[_A-Za-z0-9-\\+]+(\\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*@[A-Za-z0-9-]+(\\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)*(\\.[A-Za-z]{2,})$";
    private Pattern pattern;
    private Matcher matcher;
    private static final int REQUEST_CODE = 1;
    private Users users = null;
    private int emailExist = 0;
    private TextWatcher textWatcher = new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            checkFieldForEmptyValue();
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sign_up2stp);
        email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);
        email.setText(getEmail());
        email.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);
    }


    public String getEmail(){
        String possibleEmail = null;
        Pattern emailPattern = Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS; // API level 8+
        Account[] accounts = AccountManager.get(SignUp2stp.this).getAccounts();
        for (Account account : accounts) {
            if (emailPattern.matcher(account.name).matches()) {
                possibleEmail = account.name;
            }
        }
        return possibleEmail;
    }

    public void signUpActivity3stp(View view){
        email = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.email);
        pattern = Pattern.compile(EMAIL_PATTERN);
        TextView emailErrorHandle = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.emailErrorHandle);
        if(validateEmail(email.getText().toString())){         
            startActivity(new Intent(SignUp2stp.this,SignUp3stp.class).putExtra("email",email.getText().toString()));

        }else{
            //Handle invalid email error
            email.setError("O seu email deve ser no formato: [user@dominio.com]");

        }
    }

    public boolean validateEmail(String mail){
        matcher = pattern.matcher(mail);
        return matcher.matches();
    }

    public void checkFieldForEmptyValue(){
        button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_continue_a2);
        email = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.email);
        if(email.getText().toString().trim().isEmpty()){
            button.setEnabled(false);
        }else{
            button.setEnabled(true);
        }
    }
}
```

---

**5th activity**

```
    public class SaveUserDB extends Activity {
    private ProgressBar spinner;
    private Users users;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_save_user_db);
        spinner = (ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.spinner);
        users = (Users) getIntent().getExtras().getSerializable("users");
        new AsyncrTask().execute();

    }

    private class AsyncrTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Integer>{

        @Override
        protected Integer doInBackground(Void... params){
            try{
                return new UserDAO().signUp(users);
            }catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        protected void onPreExecute(){
            spinner.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Integer result){
            Intent intent = new Intent(SaveUserDB.this, SignUp2stp.class);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putSerializable("users",users);
            intent.putExtras(bundle);
            if(result == 0){
                startActivity(intent);
            }else if(result == 1){
                //User email exists. Go to 1st activity Prompt user to enter other email


            }else if (result == 2){
                //User phone exists. Prompt user to enter other phone number

            }else{
                // Success and go to login activity
            }
            spinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            super.onPostExecute(result);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "resend to the server side" means "go to the 5th Activity"?

Answer (score 0):

Set flags or bundle for `intent` when start activity and check it. You will know from what method this activity is started from. But it is not a right solution. Use fragmetns and it's simplify your's code and logic